# Can the Sharingan Copy Hidden Jutsu?

Tags: naruto, boruto

The Sharingan copies techniques, but i want to understand can the sharingan copy hidden technique like the shadow style jutsu?

Because according to "narutowikia website" the sharingan copies hand seals, and since the nara clan, ino clan e.t.c that uses hand seals in performing their secret jutsu, why have I never seen a sharingan user copy secret jutsu when its not a "kekkai genkai"?

Thanks, I hope my question is simple.

Comment: A sharingan user can copy those techniques. There are not many uchihas left, and those left have strong MS abilities so they never copy such small techniques. And  using a secret technique of your own village may not be a good thing. So, kakashi may have copied it but never used it to show respect to those clans, or he never copied it to keep it secret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I completely agree with Turamarth's response, I want to point out some aspects of "why" they can not copy secret/hidden techniques.

A Sharingan user can copy all types of jutsus techniques: ninjutsu, genjutsu and taijutsu.

The examples are:

- **Ninjutsu**, we can see it in Kakashi who is an expert.
- **Gentjutsu**, we can see it in Itachi copying it from Kurenai.
- **Taijutsu**, the best example of this is Sasuke using the Lee taijutsu.

In other hand, we have the special exceptions that are:

- **Kekkei Genkai / Tota / Mora:** This can't be copied cause this aren't techniques, this are a genetic abilities.**(1)**
- **Hidden jutsus:** These techniques also cannot be copied through any means of simple observation, but this techniques can be taught to anyone. A few hidden techniques require a special ability or lineage and as such are usually pride and fame of the clan that possess them. Also, the most of these techniques are based on a Yin-Yang manipulation and this isn't a trivial knowledge.**(2)**
- **Summoning Jutsus:** These techniques first need to sign a contract with the owner blood for to be able to do it.
- **Nature Transformations:** They can't mimic a jutsu with a nature transformation that they haven't learned to perform.**(3)**

More explanation:

**(1)** Dust Release techniques these techniques are not genetic, as Onoki stated that Mu passed the secrets of Dust Release on to him. (Naruto chapter 525)

**(2)** For special abilities or lineage it mean some special characteristic of some one who use these techniques, like the big size of the people of the Akimichi clan.

**(3)** Nature transformations are Fire, Wind, Earth, Water, Lightning, and the other derivatives.

---

**[A]** So the answer is no, with only the Sharingan they can't copy hidden jutsus.

Comment: @Logan M I intentionally changed Hidden to Hiden, which I believe is the correct spelling. [Hiden Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hiden)

Comment: @Wondercricket I don't know anything about Naruto, but the question and other parts of the answer use the English term "Hidden" rather than the Japanese term 秘伝 (*hiden*). If the latter is correct then it should be consistently used everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

> Sharingan users need the prerequisite abilities before they can mimic a jutsu they have...
>   [Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sharingan)

and

> Many hiden techniques are rooted in Yin–Yang Release, for example is Yin Release used in the Nara clan's Shadow Imitation Technique and Yang Release in the Akimichi clan's Multi-Size Technique. [Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hiden)

So the answer would be yes if the sharingan user has the necessary abilities to perform the technique.
It is similar to the reason why the rasengan cannot be copied. The user can see the chakra and how it moves but unless he can control his own like that he won't be able perform it.
The jutsus of the Nara and Yamanaka have hand seals but it is only one and the majority of the technique is rather manipulation of the chakra.

Comment: i see, so what you mean is that they can copy the shadow style only if they have been trained on how to manipulate chakra like the nara clan since it requires manipulation of chakra similar to rasengan.

Comment: So that means, the training nara clan members receive from their childhood is absolutely necessary to be able to use the technique efficiently?

Comment: @trim24 yes is necessary for use the technique.